# Ambiguous regex selector for behat step

Tags: regex, behat

I am trying to match behat steps in the following formats (item, email or client could be swapped for other words).

```
I want to remove item 1
I want to remove email 4 from client 3
```

In SchemaContext I am matching with the following:

```
/**
* @Given /^I want to remove (.+) (\d+)$/
* @Given /^I want to remove (.+) (\d+) from (.+) (\d+)$/
*/
public function iWantToRemove($object, $object_id, $parent = false, $parentId = false) 
{
  // Do stuff.
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Ambiguous match of "I want to remove email 3 from client 4":
    to `/^I want to remove (.+) (\d+)$/` from SchemaContext::iWantToRemove()
    to `/^I want to remove (.+) (\d+) from (.+) (\d+)$/` from SchemaContext::iWantToRemove()
```

I'm struggling to find the correct regex / approach to match both formats correctly and run them through the same method. I'd appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Are you testing your regex abilities? What is the need for adding complexity to your code? As far as I can see you step definitions are distinctive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `I want to remove email 4 from client 3` does indeed match both your regexes. I suggest changing the first one from `/^I want to remove (.+) (\d+)$/` to `/^I want to remove (\D+) (\d+)$/`.

Comment: Totally off-topic, but if you're finding the regexes fiddly, I believe Behat 3 offers a simpler system by default, where the step annotations are more readable. Maybe upgrade to version 3 and check it out?

Comment: Thank you this does exactly what I need in this case.